# Image Source In ControlTemplate WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a ControlTemplate which is for the Button control, in the ControlTemplate I have Image control which is used to displayed in the button, Now I want to set the Image Source at runt time as I have to copy paste the ControlTemplate for each of the button to set new image for new button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you just bind the ImageSource property to a property within your view model?

Comment: Can you explain your answer more ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

- http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/01/create-wpf-image-button-through-attached-properties
- http://blogs.msdn.com/knom/archive/2007/10/31/wpf-control-development-3-ways-to-build-an-imagebutton.aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vswpfdesigner/thread/8ba13699-7f7f-4ab6-8e3e-f7d787355d81

Hope this helps.
Regards,
Mihir Gokani

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking there are two ways you can set an image source at run time (the code samples below are in pseudo-code and would not compile):

1) In XAML using binding where the source of the binding will be some object's property containing the image source (this is the scenario Slugster was talking about):

This would be your object:

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public string ImageURI {get;set;}
}
```

and will be presented by XAML where you have your button with image, and image source is set through binding:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source=ViewModel; Path=ImageURI}"/>
```

2) By setting the image source from code-behind.

this will be your XAML where you have the button with image:

```
<Image x:Name="theImage"/>
```

and in the code-behind you set the source of that image:

```
theImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("yor image uri"));
```

Comment: In my case The image control in placed in the ControlTemplate and I have to assign the Source of the Image control , right now I am assigning it in ControlTemplate and I have created ControlTemplate for every button on which I have to apply the style. My Question is that I want to create One controlTemplate for all button control and in that ControlTemplate I want to assign, not in the controlTemplate.
hope you get my point

Answer (score 0):

You can access an item from inside the template by using the [`GetTemplateChild(string childName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild.aspx) method (with the name of your element as defined in the XAML), for example - If your image was defined like this:

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Stretch="Fill" />
```

then you would call this method like this:

```
Image myImage = GetTemplateChild("MyImage") as Image;

if (myImage != null)
{
    myImage.Source = "/Images/MyPicture.jpg";
}
```

Note:  You will not be able to use this method until **AFTER** [`OnApplyTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate.aspx) has been called for the control.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button x:Class="FunitureCtlLib.PressedImageButton"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="uc"><!--MinHeight="25" MinWidth="50"-->
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Image Name="imgDefault" Source="{Binding Path=DefaultImageSource,ElementName=uc}" Stretch="{Binding Path=ImageStretch,ElementName=uc}"></Image>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" TargetName="imgDefault" Value="{Binding Path=PressedImageSource,ElementName=uc}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Color="Black" Direction="0" Opacity="0.6" RenderingBias="Performance" ShadowDepth="0" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Color="White" Direction="0" Opacity="0.6" RenderingBias="Performance" ShadowDepth="0" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

```
 /// <summary>
/// ImageButton.xaml 
/// </summary>
public partial class PressedImageButton : Button
{

    #region dependency property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(PressedImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(DefaultImageSourceChangedCallback)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PressedImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(PressedImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(PressedImageSourceChangedCallback)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageStretchProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageStretch", typeof(Stretch), typeof(PressedImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(Stretch.None, new PropertyChangedCallback(ImageStretchChangedCallback)));

    #endregion       

    #region callback

    private static void DefaultImageSourceChangedCallback(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null && sender is PressedImageButton)
        {
            PressedImageButton imgbtn = sender as PressedImageButton;
            imgbtn.OnDefaultImageSourceChanged(e.OldValue, e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    private static void PressedImageSourceChangedCallback(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null && sender is PressedImageButton)
        {
            PressedImageButton imgbtn = sender as PressedImageButton;
            imgbtn.OnPressedImageSourceChanged(e.OldValue, e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    private static void ImageStretchChangedCallback(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null && sender is PressedImageButton)
        {
            PressedImageButton imgbtn = sender as PressedImageButton;
            imgbtn.OnImageStretchChanged(e.OldValue, e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region public property

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public ImageSource DefaultImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(DefaultImageSourceProperty) as ImageSource;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(DefaultImageSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public ImageSource PressedImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(PressedImageSourceProperty) as ImageSource;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(PressedImageSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public Stretch ImageStretch
    {
        get
        {
            return (Stretch)this.GetValue(ImageStretchProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ImageStretchProperty, value);
        }
    }       

    #endregion        

    #region protected method

    protected void OnDefaultImageSourceChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        //viewmodel.DefaultImageSource = newValue as ImageSource;
        this.DefaultImageSource = newValue as ImageSource;
    }

    protected void OnPressedImageSourceChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        //viewmodel.PressedImageSource = newValue as ImageSource;
        this.PressedImageSource = newValue as ImageSource;
    }

    protected void OnImageStretchChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        //viewmodel.ImageStretch = (Stretch)newValue;
        this.ImageStretch = (Stretch)newValue;
    }

    #endregion

    #region construct

    public PressedImageButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(PressedImageButton_Loaded);
    }

    #endregion

    #region private event

    void PressedImageButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }       

    #endregion
}
```